# How to organize your static text in a single page app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Imagine you have a single page applications with lot of static text in a reactjs app.

for example :

```
import Block from './components/block';

const arr = [
    {
        name: 'block1',
        text: '<p>Lot of static text 1</p>'
    },
    {
        name: 'block2',
        text: '<p>Lot of static text 2</p>'
    },
    {
        name: 'block3',
        text: '<p>Lot of static text 3</p>'
    },
    {
        name: 'block4',
        text: '<p>Lot of static text 4</p>'
    }
];

...
render() {
    return (
        arr.map((a, i) => {
            return (
                <Block key={i} text={a.text} />
            );
        })
    );
}
...
```

So the "Lot of static text" are very bigger.

How do you organize this text in all components ? Do you create a model.js file in the repo components or something ? there are a best practice for this ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can create one JSON file for the same and fetch each detail using http.
- You can store you data in some Global Service and use whenever needed by importing that file.
- Also you can create model.js file for the same.

But i would like to suggest first one, if you have to use for limited time else second option is good.

Comment: glad to know that help you :)

Answer (score 0):

ES7 suggests to store static data and methods inside static classes (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static). This is the current best practice.